# I can't change the mediaPlayer volume using a seekBar. mp.setVolume() does not work

Tags: android, media-player

OK, this is my last try of to know why the `mp.setVolume()` does not work, after that I'll throw in the towel. I already asked this to half world and seems that no one know. Ok, this time I'll post the whole code, if anyone know why the `mp.setVolume()` method does not work anyway, **PLEASE**, let me know. **I really thank**.

**Note** - the sounds are stored in the raw folder

**Code:**

**class to store constants**

```
public abstract class Constantes {

    public static String[] labels = {
            "Som 1",
            "Som 2",
            "Som 3",
            "Som 4",
            "Som 5"
    };

    public static int[] rawIds = {
            R.raw.alarm,
            R.raw.battery_caution,
            R.raw.beep_beep,
            R.raw.call_connect,
            R.raw.camera_focus
    };
}
```

**mediaPlayer class**

```
public class LoopMediaPlayer {

    private Context ctx = null;
    private int rawId = 0;

    private MediaPlayer currentPlayer = null;
    private MediaPlayer nextPlayer = null;

    public static LoopMediaPlayer create(Context ctx, int rawId) {
        return new LoopMediaPlayer(ctx, rawId);
    }

    private LoopMediaPlayer(Context ctx, int rawId) {
        this.ctx = ctx;
        this.rawId = rawId;

        currentPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this.ctx, this.rawId);
        currentPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
                currentPlayer.start();
            }
        });

        createNextMediaPlayer();
    }

    private void createNextMediaPlayer() {
        nextPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(ctx, rawId);
        currentPlayer.setNextMediaPlayer(nextPlayer);
        currentPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(onCompletionListener);
    }

    private MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener onCompletionListener = new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
            mediaPlayer.release();
            currentPlayer = nextPlayer;

            createNextMediaPlayer();
        }
    };

    public void stopPlayer() {
        if (currentPlayer != null && currentPlayer.isPlaying()) {
            currentPlayer.stop();
            currentPlayer.release();
        }

        if (nextPlayer != null && nextPlayer.isPlaying()) {
            nextPlayer.stop();
            nextPlayer.release();
        }
    }

    public void setPlayerVolume(float volume) {
        //I already tried this
//        float finalV = (float) (1 - (Math.log(MainActivity.mxVol - volume) / Math.log(MainActivity.mxVol)));
//        currentPlayer.setVolume(1- finalV, 1- finalV);
//        nextPlayer.setVolume(1- finalV, 1- finalV);
//
        //and this too
////        float finalV = ((volume * 100) / MainActivity.mxVol) / 100;

        currentPlayer.setVolume(volume, volume);
        nextPlayer.setVolume(volume, volume);

    }
}
```

**main activity**

```
@SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private TextView tvCurVol;
    private SeekBar skVol;
    private int iniVol = -1;
    private SonsAdapter adapter;
    private SparseArray<LoopMediaPlayer> players = new SparseArray<>();
    private int pos = -1;
    public static int mxVol = -1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        inits();
    }

    private AdapterView.OnItemClickListener onItemClick() {
        return new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                if (players.get(i) == null) {
                    LoopMediaPlayer player = LoopMediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, Constantes.rawIds[i]);

                    players.put(i, player);
                } else {
                    LoopMediaPlayer player = players.get(i);
                    player.stopPlayer();

                    players.remove(i);
                }
            }
        };
    }

    private AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener onItemLongClick() {
        return new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {

                if (players.get(i) != null) {
                    SonsModel model = (SonsModel) adapter.getItem(i);
                    pos = i;

                    int curVol = model.getVolume();

                    skVol.setProgress(curVol);
                    skVol.setEnabled(true);
                    skVol.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(onProgressChange());

                    return true;
                }

                return false;
            }
        };
    }

    private SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener onProgressChange() {
        return new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int i, boolean b) {
                LoopMediaPlayer player = players.get(pos);
                SonsModel model = (SonsModel) adapter.getItem(pos);

                /* I tried change volume this way and so how on method 
                  setPlayerVolume() of LoopMediaPlayer class */
                float volume = ((i * 100) / mxVol) / 100;

                player.setPlayerVolume(volume);
                model.setVolume(i);
                tvCurVol.setText("Volume Atual - " + i);
            }

            @Override
            public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
                seekBar.setEnabled(false);
            }
        };
    }

    private void inits() {
        AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager) getSystemService(AUDIO_SERVICE);
        ListView lvSons = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvSons);
        tvCurVol = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvCurVol);
        skVol = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.skVol);


        mxVol = audioManager.getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
        TextView tvMxVol = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvMxVol);
        tvMxVol.setText("Volume Maximo - " + mxVol);
        skVol.setMax(mxVol);
        skVol.setEnabled(false);

        iniVol = audioManager.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
        tvCurVol.setText("Volume Atual - " + iniVol);

        adapter = new SonsAdapter(this, createModelList());
        lvSons.setAdapter(adapter);
        lvSons.setOnItemClickListener(onItemClick());
        lvSons.setOnItemLongClickListener(onItemLongClick());
    }

    private List<SonsModel> createModelList() {
        List<SonsModel> modelList = new ArrayList<>();

        for (int i = 0; i < Constantes.labels.length; i++) {
            modelList.add(new SonsModel(Constantes.labels[i], Constantes.rawIds[i], iniVol));
        }

        return modelList;
    }
}
```

**adapter**

```
public class SonsAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private Context ctx;
    private List<SonsModel> sonsList;

    public SonsAdapter(Context ctx, List<SonsModel> sonsList) {
        this.ctx = ctx;
        this.sonsList = sonsList;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return sonsList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int i) {
        return sonsList.get(i);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int i) {
        return i;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {

        ViewHolder holder;

        if (view == null) {
            holder = new ViewHolder();

            view = LayoutInflater.from(ctx).inflate(R.layout.adapter_row, viewGroup, false);

            holder.tvRow = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvRow);

            view.setTag(holder);
        } else {

            holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();

        }

        SonsModel model = sonsList.get(i);

        holder.tvRow.setText(model.getLabel());

        return view;
    }

    private class ViewHolder {
        TextView tvRow;
    }
}
```

finally last class: som model

```
public class SonsModel {

    private String label;
    private int rawId;
    private int volume;

    public SonsModel(String label, int rawId, int volume) {
        this.label = label;
        this.rawId = rawId;
        this.volume = volume;
    }

    public String getLabel() {
        return label;
    }

    public int getRawId() {
        return rawId;
    }

    public int getVolume() {
        return volume;
    }

    public void setVolume(int volume) {
        this.volume = volume;
    }
}
```

**Layouts**

**main activity layout**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.seekbarmediavolume.MainActivity"
    tools:ignore="HardcodedText">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16sp"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="Sons"
        android:textSize="22sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvMxVol"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16sp"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:textSize="22sp" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/lvSons"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvCurVol"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16sp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:textSize="22sp" />

    <SeekBar
        android:id="@+id/skVol"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>
```

**adapter row layout**

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/tvRow"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:textColor="#f00"
    android:textSize="16sp" />
```

Comment: What's the error message? Also, provide us only the important part of your code.

Comment: Please read [ask], [tour], and consider whittling all of this down to a single issue at a time, as an [mcve].

Comment: Hi @Sakuto thanks, there isn't any message, the code compile and execute normally, but the volume just "blinked" and then came back to the system volume, it didn't stay at the setted volume on mp.setVolume(). And about the whole code, I just post it this way (including the layouts) to facilitate, this way if anyone want to give a try is only ctrl+c and ctrl+v, but the important parts are all commented, including what I did before and didn't work too. :)